# Per-Component value for CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX with RPM Generator

Tags: cmake, rpm, rpmbuild

I am trying to set a per-component value for `CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX` when using the RPM generator, but I'm not having any success.

The [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/rpm.html#variable:CPACK_RPM_%3CCOMPONENT%3E_PACKAGE_PREFIX) for `CPACK_RPM_<COMPONENT>_PACKAGE_PREFIX` says that:

> May be used to set per component CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX for
> relocatable RPM packages.

However, this doesn't seem to be the case.

Here is a simple `CMakeLists.txt` that demonstrates the problem:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(FooBar
    VERSION 0.1.0
)

add_executable(foo foo.cpp)
add_executable(bar bar.cpp)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS foo
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
    COMPONENT Foo_Comp
)

install(TARGETS bar
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
    COMPONENT Bar_Comp
)

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR ${FooBar_VERSION_MAJOR})
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR ${FooBar_VERSION_MINOR})
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH ${FooBar_VERSION_PATCH})

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_RELOCATABLE ON)    
set(CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX "/tmp/foobar")

set(CPACK_RPM_COMPONENT_INSTALL ON)    
#set(CPACK_RPM_FOO_COMP_PACKAGE_PREFIX "/tmp/foo")
#set(CPACK_RPM_BAR_COMP_PACKAGE_PREFIX "/tmp/bar")

set(CPACK_RPM_EXCLUDE_FROM_AUTO_FILELIST_ADDITION "/tmp")

include(CPack)
```

As is, the example works fine: when the target `install` is built, the executables are install to `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}`, and when the RPM is generated and that is used to install the files, they go to `${CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}`.

The issue is when the commented-out lines are uncommented. Instead of installing each component to its respective packaging prefix, they are still installed using `CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX`, but now they are no longer relocatable (i.e. `--prefix` and `--relocate` are no longer supported with the `rpm` command).

If the install command are changed to:

```
install(TARGETS foo
    DESTINATION "/tmp/foo/${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}"
    COMPONENT Foo_Comp
)

install(TARGETS bar
    DESTINATION "/tmp/bar/${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}"
    COMPONENT Bar_Comp
)
```

then the packages are relocatable and RPM installs them as expected, but `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` no longer works correctly.

Looking through the code for the CPackRPM module, it doesn't seem like there is a variable that I can set to achieve my desired outcome, but hopefully I'm missing something.

Comment: Maybe https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22926